# Java HashMap crazy behavior with duplicate keys

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

This is really weird. Here's my code:

```
Map<Text,Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<Text,Integer>();
Text currentBrowser = new Text();

// update map with browser frequencies
while(values.hasNext()){
    currentBrowser = values.next();
    if (frequencies.containsKey(currentBrowser))
        frequencies.put(currentBrowser, frequencies.get(currentBrowser) + 1);
    else
        frequencies.put(currentBrowser, new Integer(1));
}
```

The idea is that `values` is a `Iterator<Text>`, and it contains a list of browsers (Chrome, IE, etc.). I simply want to create a map that will store the frequency of each browser (if Chrome appears 3 times in the list - I want its value to be 3, etc.)

The trouble is that this doesn't work. When I debug it step-by-step, here's what happens:
The first browser is Explorer, and it puts it in the map correctly:
`{Explorer=1}`. Next comes Safari, so it goes into the `else`, but this is what happens to the map: `{Safari=1, Safari=1}`! Next two browsers are Safari, and these it does insert appropriately: `{Safari=1, Safari=3}`, but then comes Firefox and this is what happens: `{Firefox=1, Firefox=1, Firefox=3}`. So you can see that each time a new key is inserted into the map, it also changes all other keys. The first Firefox should actually be Explorer, the second should be Firefox, and the third should be Safari.

What is happening here?

Comment: What is the Text class? Is it a custom class you wrote? Can you include its code?

Comment: It's from Hadoop's org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

Comment: How do you create `Iterable<Text>`? Please post all relevant code

Comment: And how's the `values` iterator constructed? Is it possible it returns the same Text instance in each call to next()?

Comment: Have you tried just using plain `String`s instead of `Text`?

Comment: Hadoop's MapReduce creates the iterator for me, I get it already made. I will try converting the Text to String and see if this helps. Thanks

Comment: Obviously, this Text objet is not made to be used as part of a Map's keys, as it (or some important part of it, i.e. its contents) is mutated after it has been added into the map. You should probably use some method on this Text object, such as "to string" or "text value" to access a "stable" representation of it

Comment: Needs an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks guys, changing the map to String works. Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: Does `Text` implement hashCode and equals consistently?

Comment: I have no idea.. I didn't really look into Text, I just had to use it because Hadoop makes me. I thought it was quite similar to String, but I guess not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it looks like your problem is that the "currentBrowser" object is actually not changing. Meaning: you add the SAME object during each iteration; in addition to that, you are changing the INTERNAL representation of that object.

Long story short: I think the problem is that your iterator is returning the SAME object all the time.